# how to redirect a child page to parent page in the wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress

how to redirect a child page to parent page in the wordpress multisite?

is there any way to redirect a child domain which created with wordpress  multisite,to the main domain?

tnx all

Answer (score 0):

You can use something such as the [Domain Mapping](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/) plugin from wpmudev. We've used it for a good handful of clients.

or if you don't mind not being super efficient, you could put a javascript redirect in the `<head>` of your subdomain (in it's current theme in header.php probably) something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://www.domain.com/', '_self');
</script>
```

or maybe a PHP function at the top of that same file instead?

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.domain.com/"); ?>
```

the PHP MUST be used before anything is else is sent to the browser though, otherwise you'll get a "headers already sent" error and the sky will fall.

Comment: You need to make sure that the Child Site (any sites that you need to redirect) is using a theme that the live and good sites aren't using. If you use the PHP one, the code needs to be the FIRST LINE in you HEADER.PHP file. If you do the JAVASCRIPT one, the code needs to be within the `<head>` tag in your HEADER.PHP file

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect your page through htaccess.

```
Redirect http://www.yourchildthemurl.com http://yourmaintheme.com
```

By adding this code in your website you can easily redirect your website or pages.